# Macbook Pro 16" (2019 with i9 processor) performing terribly when connected to an external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, performance, displayport

I've been using my macbook pro with an external monitor for about 1 year now. In the past few weeks though, I'm struggling doing so because my macbook performance drops as soon as I connect it to my external monitor (I have a 1440p LG monitor which I connect to via a Displayport cable). The lag and the poor performance are clearly visible even if I'm simply browsing a web page. If I try to move a window around the desktop it just gets visibly laggy. Temperatures are also quite low (the lag is visible even at 55-60 degrees for the CPU).
Just so you know how bad it is, I ran two geekbench tests, with and without external monitor.

[Geekbench with external monitor](https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/8287563)

[Geekbench without external monitor](https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/8287877)

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: If you use a different cable, different cable type or different port, do you have the same problem?

Comment: Yes I tried 2 different display port cables and a HDMI cable, I tried all ports on both my monitor and macbook, the outcome remains the same.

Comment: If you boot in to safe mode, does the problem recur? What about a different user account?

Comment: I havent tried using a different account yet but safe mode doesnt work either. I just tried booting into safe mode and my macbook can't even handle today's apple wwdc stream